# completeness of derivatives of spherical harmonics

Tags: spherical-harmonics

Any function $f(\theta,\phi)$ which obeys:

$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \sin \theta |f(\theta,\phi)|^2 d\phi d\theta < \infty$

can be written in terms of spherical harmonics $Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$ as

$f(\theta,\phi) = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-l}^{l} a_{lm} Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$.

Up to an additive constant can $f(\theta,\phi)$ also be expanded in terms of the functions $\partial Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)/\partial \theta$?

Comment: Why would anyone want to do that?  This set don't form a basis of an algebra.

Comment: @user10354138. Some of the components of vector spherical harmonics depend upon the derivative. I want to know whether such components can be any scalar function on $L^2$. If the derivatives form a complete set, up to an additive constant, then my question is answered.